# How good is lambda functions to hit a REST API after a fixed amount of time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cron, schedule, mesos-chronos

I am using distributed scheduler 'Chronos'(distributed crontab) to hit a REST API after few minute of job addition(example: Add job at time T to schedule it at T+5minutes).This run on a bigger infrastructure and take care of fault-tolerant and no-data loss, however it has significant cost and I am thinking some alternative to the similar requirement. Please help if it can be done using a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do invoke a lambda function, block/wait for X seconds and continue execution, but not recommended. You cannot wait for more than 300 seconds though as thats the max timeout legally allowed by Lambda functions.

Moreover, you will hit concurrent execution limits from AWS and will need to keep calling AWS support to increase your concurrent execution limits.

Another approach to solve this problem could be to use Actor based system such as Akka, to create an Actor for each job and do the needful.

Comment: Thanks @Yeshodhan !